# Intercept .Show function calls

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I am developing an application where I want to execute custom code when a `.Show` function of any form is called. The basics is I have a `System.Windows.Form` inherited class

```
class Test : System.Windows.Forms
{
   ... do some stuff
}
```

This class will be instantiated somewhere in my code and I will call the `.Show` method in order to show the form.

When a new form is shown by my application I want to create a new button in other window which could be understood like a Taskbar.

Is any way to do this without inherit the `System.Windows.Form` class?

Comment: You can use a common method to `Show` your form, in that common method do your task..

Comment: The easy way is to Inherit from `System.Windows.Form` and use the derived type instead of `System.Windows.Form`. The hard way is IL Weaving using any library that support it like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/aop.net/msil-injection) but that is quite a learning curve.

Comment: @Tilak How does that helps? `Show` is not virtual method

Comment: You cannot intercept the Show method call, it is not virtual.  Calling a little helper method, that takes a Form as an argument, which calls its Show() method, and does other "stuff", is the simple approach.

Comment: @HansPassant I thinked about that, but what I am looking is a way to hook up to the `Show` function without modify the code of the form invocation. What I want to do is, despite the fact that all the code is written by me, create a screen area wich behaves as a taskbar and could list all the shown forms.

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to the [Shown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-Event. This way you don't necessarily have to create a derived class. Here is an example, that displays a new Form when a button is pressed. When the created Form is shown, the event displays a MessageBox (this is the part where your button creation logic would come in). I also subscribed to the FormClosed event, where you would want to remove the button from the Taskbar.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form popup = new Form();
    popup.Shown += popup_Shown;
    popup.FormClosed += popup_FormClosed;

    popup.Show();
}

void popup_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    //TODO:Remove button from taskbar
    MessageBox.Show("Popup closed.");
}

void popup_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TODO:Add button to taskbar
    MessageBox.Show("Popup shown.");
}
```

---

Since you wanted to change the main form as little as possible, here is another approach. This time we utilize a PopupManager class with static events (be sure to unsubscribe, otherwise you might run into memory leaks). However, we now need a derived popup class that raises the appropriate events in the PopupManager.

MainForm.cs

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PopupManager.PopupClosed += PopupManager_PopupClosed;
        PopupManager.PopupOpened += PopupManager_PopupOpened;
    }

    void PopupManager_PopupOpened(object sender, PopupStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Popup.Caption + " was opened");
    }

    void PopupManager_PopupClosed(object sender, PopupStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Popup.Caption + " was closed");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopupForm popup = new PopupForm("TestPopup");
        popup.Show();
    }
```

PopupManager.cs

```
public static class PopupManager
{
    static PopupManager()
    {
        openForms = new List<PopupForm>();
    }

    private static List<PopupForm> openForms;

    public static event EventHandler<PopupStateChangedEventArgs> PopupOpened;
    public static event EventHandler<PopupStateChangedEventArgs> PopupClosed;

    internal static void AddPopup(PopupForm popup)
    {
        if (openForms.Contains(popup))
            throw new ArgumentException("Popup already open", "popup");

        openForms.Add(popup);

        if (PopupOpened != null)
            PopupOpened(null, new PopupStateChangedEventArgs() { Popup = popup });
    }

    internal static void RemovePopup(PopupForm popup)
    {
        if (!openForms.Contains(popup))
            throw new ArgumentException("Popup not open", "popup");

        openForms.Remove(popup);

        if (PopupClosed != null)
            PopupClosed(null, new PopupStateChangedEventArgs() { Popup = popup });
    }
}

public class PopupStateChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public PopupForm Popup {get; set;}
}
```

PopupForm.cs

```
public class PopupForm : Form
{
    public string Caption { get; private set; }


    public PopupForm(string caption)
    {
        this.Caption = caption;
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        PopupManager.AddPopup(this);
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        PopupManager.RemovePopup(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer ChrisK, but the point about this solutions is that I must subscribe those events manually where I create the instance of the form. What i am looking is a way to do that without modify the code that instantiates the form at all.

Comment: Well, the spawned Form has to have access to the TaskBar in that case. You could create a singleton that contains informations about all the spawned popups. Then a derived PopupForm will enter itself into that singleton. But the main form would still need to subscribe to updates of that singleton, although it would be in just one place.

Comment: +1. @mmatachana - this is where refactoring code to centralize creation of objects shines. If your code for creation of objects would be in single place you'll have no problem to add listeners for all new forms. Basic form suggested by Hans Passant (create method that wraps creation/show of a form), but you can go all the way and use some dependency injection framework. Check out (Factory)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(design_pattern)] and (factory method pattern)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern] for more details